# How to come back to app after hitting the app url scheme in web view

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, callback, url-scheme

I want to come back after hitting the app scheme as the OAuth process.

I have entered the URL scheme in the app like this in the info.plist file

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.flow.tones</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>flowTonesApp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

And hitting the flowTonesApp:// in the URL of the webview/ SFSafariViewController but not coming back to app and not calling method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
```

So please let me know how to do it, I have tried many of tutorials but they didn't work.

I have checked that when I try to hit URL in the Safari browser of Simulator or device it opens my app but when I tried to hit within the app it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate method of `UIWebView`.

```
    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {    
        let surl = request.URL?.absoluteString    
        if surl.contains("flowTonesApp") {    
           // RETURN TO APP
           return false
        }    
        return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Parth
Yes, I Know this.
But I want to do it with the callback URL scheme. And I am using the WKWebView by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 3:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var mWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mWebView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          mWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        print("request: \(request.description)")
        if request.description == "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login"{
            stopLoading()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func stopLoading() {
        mWebView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.comeBackToApp()
    }

    func comeBackToApp()  {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            //   **or Used Push for where you want to go in your app**
      /*
         vc = 
         self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
          "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
       */
    }
}
```